# Convert data into UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert Data into UnsafeMutablePointer . 
Which I am encountering compilation warnings and issues.
Appreciate the much-needed solution by anyone.

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant code into your question (as text). Clearly show the relevant errors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withUnsafeMutableBytes`, `bindMemory` and `baseAddress`. E.g.

```
// build sample `Data` with three `Double`

let foo = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
var data = foo.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }

// or, if a single value
//
// let foo = 42.0
// var data = withUnsafeBytes(of: foo) { Data($0) }

// print the hex representation

print(data as NSData)

// now convert the `Data` back to `Double`

data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { rawBufferPointer in
    let bufferPointer = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self)

    // this is the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>`

    guard let pointer = bufferPointer.baseAddress else { return }
    print(pointer)

    // or, if you want the actually want the `Double` values, you can just iterate ...

    for value in bufferPointer {
        print(value)
    }

    // ... or you can use subscripts

    for i in 0 ..< bufferPointer.count {
        print(bufferPointer[i])
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer`, the `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>`, and the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>` should only be used from within this closure.

There used to be a rendition of `withUnsafeMutableBytes` that retrieved this `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` directly, but it’s been deprecated. But you can use the above.

Note, with [`bindMemory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawbufferpointer/2949653-bindmemory), you must make sure that:

> The memory must be uninitialized or initialized to a type that is layout compatible with `T`. If the memory is uninitialized, it is still uninitialized after being bound to `T`.

Obviously the above example is fine, but we obviously can’t comment on your case without a little more context about how and why you’re doing this.